# Second XRDP user can't connect to GUI on Azure VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, rdp, xrdp

I am currently running an Ubuntu 14 VM in Azure. I have successfully followed the steps to enable xrdp and install xfce4. I am able to successfully get to the GUI with the first user account I created in Putty with Windows RDP. I have a second user that was also created in Putty, however, I am unable to connect to the GUI under the second user name.

I once again followed the steps to add the GUI to the azure vm under the second user name. However, I am constantly getting an error connecting. Please see the attached photo.

I am at a loss for how to get this work. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Below is the list of commands that were used to install xrdp and xfce4.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
sudo service xrdp restart
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: you may get better answers from http://askubuntu.com

Comment: do your second user have a password ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 (installing ubuntu-desktop) might mess things up. Only installing xfce4 has always worked for me, as in this blog post:
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks good, but make sure the file in step 8 is executable.

```
chmod +x ~/.xsession
```

If that still fails, try additionally setting the contents of that file to this line:

```
exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session
```

Answer (score 0):

you must login with ssh in the second user and say you want that session to be available for xrdp:

```
echo xfce4-session /.xsession
```

and then you can try the RDP connection.

That worked for me.